# How to update observable collection on property change and also store it on every change?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, listbox, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

I have dynamic listbox contains textbox to display list items and so I can edit listbox item. My application setting file contains  string collection which I want to bind for that listbox. I also want to update that setting files on every change of listbox item, I created class which implements INotifyProprtyChanged. I have converted string collection from settings file into observable collection of custom type which has string property.  I bind textbox to property of that custom class and update source property on property change. I want to update observable collection as well. and that updates my app setting file as well. Please help me on this. Any help would be really appreciated. My code:

```
public class WindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private ObservableCollection<UrlModel> customcollection;

    public ObservableCollection<UrlModel> CustomCollection
    {
        get { return customcollection; }
        set
        {
            customcollection = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("CustomCollection");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    public WindowViewModel()
    {
        List<string> customlist = Properties.Settings.Default.CustomList.Cast<string>().ToList();
        List<UrlModel> urllist = new List<UrlModel>();
        urllist = customlist.Select(item => new UrlModel() { urlString = item }).ToList();
        CustomCollection = new ObservableCollection<UrlModel>(urllist);
    }
}

public class UrlModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string url;

    public string urlString
    {
        get { return url; }
        set
        {
            url = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("urlString");

        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));

    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ViewModel = new WindowViewModel();
        ListTwo.ItemsSource = ViewModel.CustomCollection;
    }

    private WindowViewModel viewModel;

    public WindowViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewModel; }
        set{
            viewModel = value;
            DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add property changed event handler for each url when inserting into `ObservableCollection`

```
public WindowViewModel()
{
    List<string> customlist = Properties.Settings.Default.CustomList.Cast<string>().ToList();
    List<UrlModel> urllist = new List<UrlModel>();
    urllist = customlist.Select(item => new UrlModel() { urlString = item }).ToList();
    CustomCollection = new ObservableCollection<UrlModel>(urllist);

    foreach(var model in CustomCollection)
    {
        model.PropertyChaged += SettingsUpdater; //Settings update fucntion
    }
}
```

A naive implementation of `SettingsUpdater` would just update the whole list of urls in settings whenever one of them changes.

Comment: Thanks for input but how can I save my collection with updated property back to app settings file?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using data template to make your listbox editable. If that is the case, while binding the text, include Text="{Binding urlString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" in the Xaml code.

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Name="EditableText" Text="{Binding urlString,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Yes I am doing this and Property gets updated on change... and UI also gets updated... but I want to store that change into application setting file on every change.. How can I save my update on setting file?